# On Joomla html tabs default code, how to change the active tag using external javascript

Tags: javascript, joomla, tabs, mootools

In a joomla component I am making, I am using joomla's default tabs functionality. It uses mootools and works like a charm.

The problem is that I need to change the active tab using javascript (from an ajax call).

I have prepared a simple example at:
http://dianthos.net/test/tabs/tabs.html

I want to be able to click on the "click here", and change the active tab.

Restrictions: I cannot modify the html, nor any of the existing javascript. 
I have to whatever I do inside the  function loadtab2()

Any ideas how I can reference it from in there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

save a reference to the Tabs instance:

```
var tabsInstance; // up the scope.

// further down
tabsInstance = new JTabs(tabs, {
    useStorage: false,
    titleSelector: 'dt.tabs',
    descriptionSelector: 'dd.tabs'
});

// event handler
el.addEvent('click', function(e) {
    e.stop();
    tabsInstance.display(2);
});
```

going by the methods available in here: http://dianthos.net/test/tabs/tabs.js

poor man's external call w/o the above goes:

```
$$("dt.tabs")[1].fireEvent('click');
```

Comment: Here is the exact HTML code I used in Joomla 3.x to move to another tab; I used SPAN instead of a hyperlink, so that it didn't move to another page. I then created a CSS to style the span to look like a hyperlink:

`<span onclick="javascript:$$('dt.tabs')[1].fireEvent('click');" class="hyperlink">click here</span>`